# Add a class with onclick js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add a class *.up* to some menu items when another item is clicked. I am using js to add the class when the link is not opened in a new tab or window i.e. when item-129 is clicked the class *up* should be added to items 126, 127 and 128 however it is not working. Below are the js and html codes that I am using.

js code

```
keypressed = null;

$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    keypressed = event.keyCode;
});

$(window).keyup(function(event) {
    keypressed = null;
});

$("#item-129").click(function(event) {
    // Don't animate if command keys or ctrl keys held down
    if (keypressed == 91 || keypressed == 92 || keypressed == 17) {
        return true;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#item-126, #item-127, item-128").addClass("up");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("href"));
        location.href = $(this).attr("href");
    });
});
```

HTML code

```
<li id="item-126" class="item-126 deeper parent">
    <span class="nav-header">About Us</span>
    <ul class="nav-child unstyled small">
        <li id="item-129" class="item-129"><a href="/v1/index.php/aboutus/bio">Bio</a>  </li>
        <li id="item-130" class="item-130"><a href="/v1/index.php/aboutus/our-clients">Our Clients</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="item-127" class="item-127"><span class="nav-header">Services</span></li>
<li id="item-128" class="item-128"><span class="nav-header">Contact Us</span></li>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to animate the menu using the class *up* then open the link in item-129.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You have of course used the developer tools (F12) to see if you got any errors, and you have verified whether the click event was fired in the first place. What was the outcome of those tests?

Comment: item-129 is wrapping a link, clicking li will trigger the link. You should trigger the click on the link and return false at the end

Comment: Looks like you have an error in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/g2a33/ (What you're passing to the `click` function is nonsensical.)

Comment: You're missing a `#` here: `$("#item-126, #item-127, item-128").addClass("up");`
You're an additional paren here : `$(this).attr("href"));`

Comment: Working: http://jsfiddle.net/g2a33/1/

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replies. I fixed the errors indicated and added `return false` to the js code but am still getting the same result i.e the link opens straight away. What I am trying to achieve is to animate the menu using the class _up_ then open the link in item-129.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/g2a33/1/

Comment: are the class names for the li items dynamically added?

Comment: @JaredFarrish what is the difference from the previous jsfiddle?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation()` (Also note that I'm running it in the `onDOMReady` event, or `$(document).ready()`, that jsFiddle adds automatically.)

Comment: @GeorgeFarrugia can you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/39james/A2eZc/1/. I used your HTML but added a class name 'item' to all li items.

Comment: @James Thanks for your insight. I did a few changes to your fiddle and got the desired effect. However when I paste the code in my js file it doesn't work:/ am I missing something?

Comment: @GeorgeFarrugia you have to add a class name "item" to all the li items, did you do that?

Comment: @James No I removed that class as one of my edits...updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A2eZc/5/

Comment: So is working your fiddle as you wanted? But "item-126" is missing a "." in your fiddle, should it be ".item-126"

Comment: .item 126 is just a header not a link

Comment: @JaredFarrish can you kindly add event.stopPropagation() and  $(document).ready() as comments?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `event.stopPropagation()` and use `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    keypressed = null;

    $(window).keydown(function(event) {
        keypressed = event.keyCode;
    });

    $(window).keyup(function(event) {
        keypressed = null;
    });

    $("#item-129").click(function(event) {
        // Don't animate if command keys or ctrl keys held down
        if (keypressed == 91 || keypressed == 92 || keypressed == 17) {
            return true;
        }

        event.stopPropagation();

        $("#item-126, #item-127, #item-128").addClass("up");

        return false;
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2a33/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I added the code but am now getting this error **Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function** on line 1.